# Delphi DataSnap function returning TStream and memory leak

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, datasnap

I am using a basic DataSnap server.
I am using XE8, windows 8.1

I have the next server function:

```
function TSrvServerMetodos.ImagePac(pront:integer): TStream;
var blob:TStream;
    strm:TMemoryStream;
begin
  with qrytemp do begin
        Params.Clear;
        SQL.Clear;
        SQL.Add('SELECT F.PICTURE FROM CLIENTES F WHERE F.PRONT=:pront');
        UnPrepare;
        Prepare;
        Params[0].Value:=pront;
        Open;
        if IsEmpty then result:=nil
        else begin
         try
              Result := CreateBlobStream(fieldbyname('pict'),bmRead);
              GetInvocationMetadata.ResponseContentType := 'image/jpeg';
         except
              Result:=nil
         end;
        end;
  end;
end;
```

My client app is an Android app. All works well and I can get the pícture  .

My doubt is about memory leak on Datasnap server.

Since result is a TStream that I created, Datasnap Server will take care to free it or I will have problems with memory leak?

Comment: How would the server know whether and when to free the stream?

Comment: @MartynA This is a DataSnap server with invocation lifecycle. You also ask what I want to know.

Comment: Sorry, my q was a bit rhetorical.  How *can* the server possibly "know" what heap allocations have been made in the routine, never mind undoing them?

Comment: In my experience you won't have a memory leak here. I use Eurekalog in my datasnap servers and they have never detected a memory leak in my methods that return streams.

Comment: @nolaspeaker: you know what they say, absence of evidence is not evidence of absence.  Put a breakpoint on the destructor of the stream your method returns.  When does it trip, and what invokes it?

Comment: I think the answer probably depends on the the value for the LifeCycle of the applicable TDSServerClass. In any event, the ClientModuleUnit is created on a thread, and the TStream instance we're talking about, is released at the end of the cycle at the latest or simply near the end of the server method invocation. (The code is too complex for me to understand at first glance)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did an experiment to look into this and the result surprised me.

Let the DataSnapServer Wizard (under File | New | Other | Delphi Projects |
DataSnap Server) create a default server project and then make the following additions

```
type
  TMyStringStream = class(TStringStream)
  public
    constructor Create(Value : String);
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

  TServerMethods1 = class(TDSServerModule)
[...]

function TServerMethods1.GetStream(Value: String): TStream;
var
  SS : TMyStringStream;
begin
  SS := TMyStringStream.Create(Value);
  SS.Position := 0;
  Result := SS;
end;

constructor TMyStringStream.Create(Value: String);
begin
  inherited Create;
  WriteString(Value);
end;

destructor TMyStringStream.Destroy;
begin
  Clear;
  inherited;
end;
```

, compile, put a breakpoint on `Clear` in `TMyStringStream.Destroy` and run.

Then, create/run a minimal client which does something like this

```
procedure TDSClientForm.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  SS : TStringStream;
  S : TStream;
begin
  SqlServerMethod2.Params[0].AsString := 'ABC123';
  SqlServerMethod2.ExecuteMethod;
  SS := TStringStream.Create;
  try
    S := SqlServerMethod2.Params[1].AsStream; //, 6{SqlServerMethod2.Params[1].Size});
    S.Position := 0;
    SS.CopyFrom(S, S.Size);
    ShowMessage(SS.DataString);
  finally
    SS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

If you then click Button2 in the client, you'll find that the server stops on
the breakpoint in `TMyStringStream.Destroy`.   This is a result of `FreeAndNil(FAllocatedReturn)`
executing in the block

```
  if not FServerSideCommand then
    try
      FreeAndNil(FAllocatedReturn)
    except
      Result := false
    end;
```

in `function TDSMethodValues.ClearReferenceParameters: boolean` in DataSnap.DSReflect.

So it looks like a Stream which is allocated in your server method AND is assigned to
its Result will be freed (whether you like it or not), so that won't leak.  But I think you should regard that as a narrow exception to the general rule that if you create a Delphi object via a local variable, you should dispose of it before the variable goes out of scope.

Comment: So, did this answer your q?